# Indecomposable modules over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}[C_p]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
I'm interested in a classification of indecomposable modules over the $\Z/p^2\Z$-group-ring $R$ of the cyclic group $C_p$ of order $p$:
$$ R = \Z/p^2\Z[C_p] = \Z/p^2\Z[T]/(T^p - 1) $$

(I actually want to replace $p^2$ with $p^n$, but I figured this would be a good place to start.)

I was hoping it would be the case that all indecomposables over $R$ were cyclic $R$-modules, which is true when we replace $\Z/p^2\Z$ with the field $\Z/p\Z$, but I don't think this is the case. Consider the $R$-module $M$ with underlying abelian group $\Z/p\Z \times \Z/p^2\Z$ where $T$ acts by the matrix
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ p & 1+p
\end{pmatrix}.\end{equation*}

By direct computation, one can verify that the cyclic submodule generated by every* nonzero element has order $p^2$. (*The element $(0,p)$ generates a submodule of order $p$, but $p\Z/p^2\Z$ is not a direct summand of $M$ even as an abelian group.) In particular, no single element generates $M$ (so it is not cyclic), but no two elements can be used to break $M$ up into a direct sum, since any direct sum must involve a submodule of order $p$.

I spoke with someone who gave me the following argument for the cyclicity of indecomposables (which I now think is false, but I don't know in which of the first two steps problem is as I'm not comfortable thinking about projective covers over this ring):

1. $M$ has a projective cover as an $R$-module.
2. The projective cover of an indecomposable module is indecomposable.
3. $R$ is local so projectives are free.
4. Free + indecomposable implies rank 1.
5. Thus every indecomposable is a quotient of $R$.

Does anyone know how I might modify this argument to something correct (but necessarily weaker)? Or maybe someone can point me toward the classification I'm looking for or a reference that will help me find it?

Comment: Do we know that $M$ has a projective cover?  As $R$ is not an algebra over a field my usual source for information about projective covers doesn't apply.

Comment: @Guest I feel the same way. As I said, there is something wrong in step 1 or 2 of the proof, and I think that might be the error.

Comment: Having thought about this some more I also suspect $2$ is wrong, even for a finite dimensional algebra over a field.  The projective cover of a *simple* module is indecomposable but in general the projective cover of a module $M$ is given by taking the direct sum of the projective covers for the simple modules in the top of $M$.  There can certainly be indecomposible modules whose tops are not indecomposible, so that would provide a counterexample to 2.

Comment: Sorry, what is the "top" of $M$?

Comment: The socle of a module $M$ is the submodule of $M$ given by summing all the simple submodules of $M$.  The top of $M$ is the quotient of $M$ by its socle.

Comment: Ah okay. In the case of the specific $M$ I wrote in the above post, its top is just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with the trivial $R$-action, so it is not simple. This does provide a counterexample to 2!